# Scrapy: ValueError('Missing scheme in request url: %s' % self._url)

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to scrape data from a webpage. The webpage is simply a bullet list of 2500 URLs. Scrapy fetch and goes to each and every URL and fetch some data ...

Here is my code

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'dknews'
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.org/uat-area/scrapy/all-news-listing']
    allowed_domains = ['example.org']

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = Selector(response)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.body, 'lxml')
        nf = NewsFields()
        ptype = soup.find_all(attrs={"name":"dkpagetype"})
        ptitle = soup.find_all(attrs={"name":"dkpagetitle"})
        pturl = soup.find_all(attrs={"name":"dkpageurl"})
        ptdate = soup.find_all(attrs={"name":"dkpagedate"})
        ptdesc = soup.find_all(attrs={"name":"dkpagedescription"})
         for node in soup.find_all("div", class_="module_content-panel-sidebar-content"):
           ptbody = ''.join(node.find_all(text=True))  
           ptbody = ' '.join(ptbody.split())
           nf['pagetype'] = ptype[0]['content'].encode('ascii', 'ignore')
           nf['pagetitle'] = ptitle[0]['content'].encode('ascii', 'ignore')
           nf['pageurl'] = pturl[0]['content'].encode('ascii', 'ignore')
           nf['pagedate'] = ptdate[0]['content'].encode('ascii', 'ignore')
           nf['pagedescription'] = ptdesc[0]['content'].encode('ascii', 'ignore')
           nf['bodytext'] = ptbody.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
         yield nf
            for url in hxs.xpath('//ul[@class="scrapy"]/li/a/@href').extract():
             yield Request(url, callback=self.parse)
```

Now the problem is that the above code scrapes around 215 out of 2500 articles. It closes by giving this error ...

> ValueError('Missing scheme in request url: %s' % self._url)

I have no idea what is causing this error ....

Any help is very appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Update 01/2019**

Nowdays Scrapy's Response instance has pretty convenient method `response.follow` which generates Request from the given URL (either absolute or relative or even `Link` object generated by `LinkExtractor`) using `response.url` as the base:

```
yield response.follow('some/url', callback=self.parse_some_url, headers=headers, ...)
```

Docs: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Response.follow

---

Code below looks like the issue:

```
 for url in hxs.xpath('//ul[@class="scrapy"]/li/a/@href').extract():
     yield Request(url, callback=self.parse)
```

if any of urls is not fully qualified, e.g. looks like `href="/path/to/page"` rather than `href="http://example.com/path/to/page"` you'll get the error. To ensure you yielding correct requests you can use `urljoin`:

```
    yield Request(response.urljoin(url), callback=self.parse)
```

Scrapy way is to use `LinkExtractor` though https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html