# How to avoid from ValueError(Missing scheme url) if the absolute url of image doesn't contain http?

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

During scraping images from the [link](http://www.thesaabsite.com/catalog/audi/2017/a3-e-tron-premium-hatchback-14l-l4/accessories-and-fluids/a-c-compressor-oil/?year=2017&make_id=73&model_id=9662&group_id=1&category_id=6928), I noticed that the url of images  something like this (data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD......).Upon inspecting,you'll get to know about the link, which if you see doesn't contain any http or www part in it. And upon execution of this code:

**spider.py**

```
img_url=response.xpath('//table/tbody/tr/td/span/a/img/@src').extract()
for urls in img_url:
    yield {"image_urls":urls}
```

I'm getting error of :

```
ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: d
```

**setting.py** looks like this

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {'scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline': 1}
IMAGES_STORE = 'C:\Users\Danial\Desktop\saab_pics\output'
```

Comment: Did y read this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42026244/scrapy-valueerrormissing-scheme-in-request-url-s-self-url

Comment: @Zhivko.Kostadinov my problem is a little bit different. I've already searched a lot and got nothing. The problem is with url which was not in the form of http or www. If you go to the link, you'll come to know more about it

Comment: The problem is that `src` attribute is not necessarily a link. In this case, it is a base64-encoded string. Scrapy `ImagesPipeline` does not support this. I guess, you need a custom pipeline to handle this case.